# Why does IE7 add tabindex="0" to elements without tabindex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm developing a web application that requries alot of keyboard navigation.

I've taken control of tab key navigation and I select all elements with the following example jQuery selection:

```
elements = $("div").find("[tabindex]:visible").not("[tabindex='0'], :disabled");
```

So I do not select invisible elements, elements that are disabled or have a tabindex of 0.

This works great in Firefox, Chrome and IE8+. Sadly, the project requires support for IE7.
For some reason IE7 seems to add tabindex="0" to elements without a tabindex set by us and `elements` contains elements with tabindex="0" in IE7 eventhough the selector should not add them.

Anyone know why IE7 behaves this way and if there's something that can be done about it?

This causes a bad performance hit in our worst case scenario where `elements` contains over 300 elements in all other browsers except IE7, which contains almost 800.

**edit:**

I've managed to write a selector that does not include elements with tabindex="0" in IE7 as well.

```
elements = $("div").find("[tabindex][tabindex!=0][tabindex!=-1]:visible:not(:disabled)");
```

Comment: There isn't probably "why" besides that in one point of history Microsoft did not care about web and whatever crap runs in IE. You probably need to add some marker, like CSS class, to discriminate between real tabindex elements and ones which you have assigned yourself as a workaround if you want to support IE7.

Comment: I guess so. However I managed to write a selector that also works for IE7 so adding CSS classes (which was our last and tedious resort) is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML uses the [tabindex attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) to control the tab order. So tabindex is added for all elements by default to make the page elements keyboard accessible. It is also used for the [focus pseudo class](http://nemisj.com/focusable/) in other browsers.

**References**

- [18F: Keyboard Access - Accessibility Guide](https://pages.18f.gov/accessibility/keyboard/)